# Why is this legal to setImageResource using file name?

Tags: android, image

I was reading this piece of code from the other App and I spot this:

[image: I was reading this piece of code from the other App and I spot this:]

Noted that those "buttons**" variables are marked red which means symbol that cannot resolved at design time. Even in debug mode, these variables are not able to resolve either.

However, the program runs perfectly fine. These variables are not defined in the whole project, so it seems the author was using the file name directly.

Is that even legal? I really can't sleep on it.

Plus, I tried to switch back using canonical "R.drawable.*" way, everything was fine except the image size had a little bit different.

Could someone explain the story behind this? Really appreciated!